# How to limit the amount of messages I can send using Twilio

Tags: twilio, limit, message, whatsapp

I'm setting up a chatbot for Whatsapp using Twilio. My question is how can I set a limit on number of messages I can send in a day? It's for my protection, so that if some bug would send over a million messages then Twilio would make me bankrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Heyoooo.  Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

To my knowledge, it's not possible to limit the sent messages on the Twilio side. To set a hard limit you'd have to count and keep track of the sent messages on your end.

There are a few things that you can do that may help already.

### Disable auto-recharge

If you're worried about going bankrupt [disable auto-recharge for your project](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135607-How-do-I-set-a-recharge-trigger-). This way you can't just send millions of messages in case your application goes wild.

### Set up usage warnings

Additionally, you can set up [usage triggers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-trigger#create-a-new-usagetrigger-with-params) that will send a webhook to a URL you define if your app hits a certain threshold value. This URL could act like kill-switch to really shut everything down after x sent messages.

### FYI, Twilio protects you of loops already

> To protect your project, messages cannot be sent more than 15 times in a 30 second window between your Twilio phone number and another number. Doing so may trigger a 14107 warning that your message rate has been exceeded.

In case something goes wild [Twilio will stop you from sending messages](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183648-Sending-and-Receiving-Limitations-on-Calls-and-SMS-Messages).

---

I hope that helps. Let me know it goes. :)